# How to override the default height of Elastic UI combobox

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I want to customize the height of `Task` combobox to match the `Date Picker`.
The style isn't getting applied when done through class or inline.

[image]

I've tried inline styling the element as:

```
 <EuiFormRow className={FilterStyles.taskFilerContainer}>
        <EuiComboBox
          fullWidth={true}
          placeholder="Task"
          options={tasks}
          selectedOptions={selectedOption}
          onChange={(v) => handleChange(v)}
          isClearable={true}
          compressed={false}
          rowHeight={60}
          style={{ height: "40px" }}   <----- Here
          className="task"
        />
      </EuiFormRow>
```

Also tried adding `!important` but of no use. 
However I'm able to override the style in browser by manually styling the `euiComboBox` class:

[image]

```
.euiComboBox .euiComboBox__inputWrap.euiComboBox__inputWrap-isClearable {
    padding-right: 58.125px;
    height: 40px; <-- Here
}
```

[image]

Is there any way to style the element by writing custom class or inline style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reducing the height of the parent container `filterContainer`. Reduced the height of element wrapping both these input fields.

```
.filterContainer{
 height: 37px
}
```